# Difference between comment.Patch and comment.Update in Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I went through method documentations both [patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/patch) and [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/update) and it looks they both doing the same.

And i also note that the [patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/patch) doesn't required the `content` of the patching comment even though its required to call the `patch()` method.

So, is the difference between `comment.patch()` and the `comment.update()` methods in Google Drive API?

PS : I'm using Google-Drive Java SDK for my implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patch is used to perform partial updates and save some bandwidth when, for instance, you only want to update a single field in a resource.

For more details about how patch work and for other performance tips, please check the Google Drive SDK documentation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/performance#patch