# Updating Google Drive Metadata with googleapiclient in python

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, metadata

I am trying to update a Test file's metadata (specifically the file's name) in Google Drive using python's Google API client library. I have used the following google resources:

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update

I haven't had had trouble connecting to googles drive API. I am merely having issues updating the filename or any other metadata that I would want to update.

My code is below:

```py
from googleapiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

from googleapiclient import errors
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload


# This is to connect to Google Drive's API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata' # drive.metadata gives me the access to read and writeover metadata
CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_id.json' # this is from Oauth when you create credentials for a good project

store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)

DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

files = DRIVE.files().list().execute().get('files', [])

print()
print("File Specific metadata")
for f in files:
    if f['name']=='Test' and f['mimeType']=='application/vnd.google-apps.document':
        print(f['name'], f['id'], f['mimeType'])
        file_id = f['id']
        print(file_id)

# First retrieve the file from the API.
print()
file = DRIVE.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()
print(file)

file['name'] = 'A'
print(file)

# Send the request to the API.
updated_file = DRIVE.files().update(fileId=file_id, body=file).execute()
```

But when I do this, I get an insufficient permissions error. I think it has something to do with the SCOPES but I am not sure.

Comment: I suggest that you use patch rather than update if you'll be performing partial updates and save some bandwidth when, for instance, you only want to update a single field in a resource. This is also suggested by a Googler in a [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15561696/5995040).

Comment: Thanks Mr.Rebot. My only concern is that patch is part of the REST v2 API and is not longer available for REST v3 from what I can tell.

Comment: Aside from using the current scope, did you try using auth/drive (full access)?

Comment: I just tried and it works! This is what I have now.                                
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' #auth/drive gives me the access to read and writeover metadata
CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_id.json' #this is from Oauth when you create credentials for a google project

store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

Comment: Nice! Try posting a bug report for the document or maybe it is really a bug when using the scope drive.metadata gives you an insufficient permission error.